# Bootstrap multiple columns folding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I need to have two columns layout but i need content to stack up.
Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kljuco/KPMCJ/.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Test 1</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Test 2</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
         <table class="table">
             <tr><th colspan="2">Test 3</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
          <table class="table">
              <tr><th colspan="2">Test 4</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div><div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div><div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

I need  "Test 3" table to be right beneath "Test 1" table.
Thnx

Comment: Did you see my updated answer with the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/KPMCJ/3/    I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your rows like this...

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Test 1</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr><th colspan="2">Test 3</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Test 2</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                 <table class="table">
                     <tr><th colspan="2">Test 4</th></tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>test</td>
                          <td>test</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div><div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

At least you can start tweaking from this to get the result you want

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that CSS should do, rather let jQuery solve your problem:

```
<table id="first" class="table"> ....
<table id="second" class="table"> ...
<table id="third" class="table"> ...

$('#third').insertBefore('#second');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, another way:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/KPMCJ/3/

The bad news is I had to duplicate the html for the second table.

The good news, no jQuery.

Take a look.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  #second {
      display:none;
  }

#second-small {
      display:table;
  }


}


@media (min-width: 766px) {

  #second-small {
      display:none;
  }


}
```